# UIView animation ignores duration when come second time on controller why?

Tags: ios

I have two ViewController A and B when first time i came from controller A to B its work fine ,But when i go back to controller A and then came back to B UIView animation block ignoring the duration time the completion block get called immediately.
Any one has any idea why this behaving like that??

***Solution***  Finally (Me & Mawoon) found the solution my own before start the animation write this single line code.

**[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];**

see below the code it will work.

```
-(void)doAnimation
{
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    view2=(UIView*)[self.view viewWithTag:100];
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
        view2.frame=CGRectMake(0, 30, 1024,768);
        view2.alpha=1.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        view2.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024,768);
        view2.alpha=0.0;
        [weakSelf doAnimation];
    }];
}
```

Comment: If you run `NSLog(@"%@", view2);` what do you see?

Comment: Are you sure you're retrieving an object from `[self.view viewWithTag:100];`

Comment: @GuyKogus (0,30,width,height);

Comment: @PanayotPanayotov yes sure view2=(UIView*)[self.view viewWithTag:100];

Comment: What's the value of self.slideDuration and how is it computed?

Comment: And what's the print-out for `view1`?

Comment: @GuyKogus leave view1 this is not concern

Comment: @Andrew i just edited code have look

Comment: is there somthing going wrong with CALayer of view?? i used this block several time but never face problem like this. I am not able to configure out why this is happening plz if any one have any clue or solution please give me.

Comment: Do you use autolayout ? If you change the frame without animation, does it work ?

Comment: And what about autolayout ? it is enabled by default, in storyboard or xib it is the first tab of the right pane.

Comment: stop working suggests this works before, do we have to ask what you changed for this to stop working? Firstly as suggested confirm that view2 is not nil, then confirm if you are using AutoLayout for the view. If you are you I would recommend removing constraints, adding them into an array then adding them back later if required

Comment: @StuartM i figure out something animation block called the completion block immediately that why its not showing any animation it ignoring the duration time 3 sec.

Comment: The `finished` parameter is there for a reason. What does that say when the completion block is being called immediately?

Comment: I've seen cases, that the animation duration is skipped in case it already has the necessary frame/alpha level. Before animation block, try to set alpha to 0.5 and frame to CGRectMake(1,1,1,1) and see if the animation appears or still skips duration.

Comment: @GuntisTreulands yes it still ignore i had set frame CGRectMake(1,1,1,1) and alpha 0.5 before animation block

Comment: what happens if You remove everything from the completion?

also - when do You call this function? (on button click?)

Comment: @GuntisTreulands same thing no change

Comment: To the OP - you should move the solution out of the question into a real answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must make the weak reference to call block itself and then enable your animation because when you pop up from view controller then animation will be release so you need to enabled the animation again.

**[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];**

So here is the complete code:

```
 -(void)doAnimation
    {
     __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
     view2=(UIView*)[self.view viewWithTag:100];
     [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
     [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{       
         view2.frame=CGRectMake(0, 30, 1024,768);
         view2.alpha=1.0       
     } completion:^(BOOL finished){  
         view2.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024,768);
         view2.alpha=0.0 
        [weakSelf doAnimation];  
     }];
     }
```